# How to write very long string that conforms with PEP8 and prevent E501

Tags: python, string, pep8

PEP8 suggests a line limit of 80 characters. But my string goes over the limit:

```
s = "this is my really, really, really, really, really, really, really long string that I'd like to shorten."
```

How should I format that to stay within the character limit? e.g.,

```
s = (
    "this is my really, really, really, really, really, really" + 
    "really long string that I'd like to shorten."
)
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Implicit concatenation might be the cleanest solution:

```
s = "this is my really, really, really, really, really, really," \
    " really long string that I'd like to shorten."
```

**Edit** On reflection I agree that Todd's suggestion to use brackets rather than line continuation is better for all the reasons he gives. The only hesitation I have is that it's relatively easy to confuse bracketed strings with tuples.

Comment: This is why I felt like an idiot posting the question. Cheers.

Comment: This is line continuation by escaping the endline, not merely implicit concatenation, and until very recently explicitly forbidden in PEP8, although now there is an allowance, but NOT for long strings. Todd's answer below is correct.

Comment: I like PEP8, but this is part of PEP8 that I don't like.  I feel like the implicit continuation is clearer, because of the possibility for confusion with tuples

Comment: Remember not to add any blank spaces after \

Answer (score 392):

Since neighboring string constants are automatically concatenated, you can code it like this:

```
s = ("this is my really, really, really, really, really, really, "  
     "really long string that I'd like to shorten.")
```

Note no plus sign, and I added the extra comma and space that follows the formatting of your example.

Personally I don't like the backslashes, and I recall reading somewhere that its use is actually deprecated in favor of this form which is more explicit. Remember "Explicit is better than implicit."

I consider the backslash to be less clear and less useful because this is actually escaping the newline character. It's not possible to put a line end comment after it if one should be necessary. It is possible to do this with concatenated string constants:

```
s = ("this is my really, really, really, really, really, really, " # comments ok
     "really long string that I'd like to shorten.")
```

---

I used a Google search of "python line length" which returns the PEP8 link as the first result, but also links to another good StackOverflow post on this topic: "[Why should Python PEP-8 specify a maximum line length of 79 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88942/why-should-python-pep-8-specify-a-maximum-line-length-of-79-characters)"

Another good search phrase would be "python line continuation".

Comment: +1: "Personally I don't like the backslashes, and I recall reading somewhere that its use is actually deprecated in favor of this form which is more explicit. Remember "Explicit is better than implicit.""

Comment: For everyone who gets a tuple and wonders why. Do not add commas to the end of the lines here, that will result in a tuple, not a string. ;)

Comment: Isn't adding the + character more explicit than the given example? I'd still consider this implicit. i.e. `"str1" + "str2"` rather than `"str1" "str2"`

Comment: I actually agree that the plus sign is more explicit, but it does a different thing. It turns the string into an expression to be evaluated, rather than specifying a single string constant in a number of pieces. I'm not certain but I think this is done during parsing whereas the expression needs to be executed later. The speed difference is probably negligible unless there are a huge number of them. But also aesthetically I prefer the automatic concatenation since it is one less cluttery character per line.

Comment: This syntax also keeps the possibility of applying string formatting like:
``('this is my really, really, really, really, really long {} '
    'that I'd really, really, really, like to {}').format(var1, var2))``

Comment: A warning: if the multiline string is a multiline formatted string, with an "f" at the beginning, the "f" needs to appear on each line.

Comment: True, the "f" needs to appear on each section that contains a replaceable part.

Comment: Your answer is helpful @Todd, thank you... but at the risk of being a little contentious the "Explicit is better than implicit" guidance tells me that keeping a single string explicitly a single string (even if it is long and breaks PEP guidelines for line length) may actually be the real answer here ;)

Comment: Well @Nij, I have to respectfully disagree on two points: first, that would not be a helpful answer to this question where Federer wants to break the strings! =) And second, I personally prefer to break strings and keep things within 80 columns to support two side-by-side windows in Sublime Text. Seeing it all at once on the screen is a more useful form of "explicit" than keeping the string unbroken and having to scroll.

Comment: Hi @Todd  To expand a little; I do not believe all strings in a program are *intended for the developer to read*; they are for end-users to read, or some other code to parse, or maybe 'only useful if you are looking up an error code' or whatever. In such cases the PEP guidelines rigidity is frustrating (to me), and actually why I went searching for info on line lengths!
I do agree, however, much code & comments _are_ for developers to read, so I do try to keep them within limited line length.
Your comment about explicit-is-better really did help me think about things! (hence the +1 :)

Answer (score 19):

I think the most important word in your question was "suggests".

Coding standards are funny things.  Often the guidance they provide has a really good basis when it was written (e.g. most terminals being unable to show > 80 characters on a line), but over time they become functionally obsolete, but still rigidly adhered to.  I guess what you need to do here is weigh up the relative merits of "breaking" that particular suggestion against the readability and mainatinability of your code.

Sorry this doesn't directly answer your question.

Comment: I totally agree. There is a similar Java style rule that has become obsolete too (IMHO).

Comment: Yes I agree, however It's been racking my head how I would abide to it in this particular example. I always try to keep classes, methods to < 80 characters, however I'd say a string like this has no effect other than perhaps a negative one.

Comment: You also need to weigh your personal preference against the community-wide coding standard.  You want new people to be able to come in and be comfortable with the code formatting from day one.

Comment: I know for my own self, I tend to stick to the 80 character limit just because I still do most of my coding in IDLE and I don't like the way it handles horizontal scrolling. (No scroll bar)

Comment: @retracile - yes, you do.  I am not saying "You must ignore the guidance", rather suggesting that in some cases the guidance is not necessarily there for the good of the community. I wasn't aware of IDLE's restrictions (as posted by Tofystedeth) but in that instance there is a striong argument for following the convention.

Comment: I frequently use an editor/shell combo like Spyder on a split screen with a browser, so I don't know that it's entirely obsolete in terms of practicality (we now have night universal large screens, but that real estate can be valuable).

Answer (score 16):

You lost a space, and you probably need a line continuation character, ie. a `\`.

```
s = "this is my really, really, really, really, really, really" +  \
    " really long string that I'd like to shorten."
```

or even:

```
s = "this is my really, really, really, really, really, really"  \
    " really long string that I'd like to shorten."
```

Parens would also work instead of the line continuation, but you risk someone thinking you intended to have a tuple and had just forgotten a comma.  Take for instance:

```
s = ("this is my really, really, really, really, really, really"
    " really long string that I'd like to shorten.")
```

versus:

```
s = ("this is my really, really, really, really, really, really",
    " really long string that I'd like to shorten.")
```

With Python's dynamic typing, the code may run either way, but produce incorrect results with the one you didn't intend.

Answer (score 6):

If you must insert a long string literal and want flake8 to shut up, you can use it's [shutting up directives](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html).  For example, in a testing routine I defined some fake CSV input.  I found that splitting it over more lines that it had rows would be mightily confusing, so I decided to add a `#  noqa: E501` as follows:

```
csv_test_content = """"STATION","DATE","SOURCE","LATITUDE","LONGITUDE","ELEVATION","NAME","REPORT_TYPE","CALL_SIGN","QUALITY_CONTROL","WND","CIG","VIS","TMP","DEW","SLP","AA1","AA2","AY1","AY2","GF1","MW1","REM"
"94733099999","2019-01-03T22:00:00","4","-32.5833333","151.1666666","45.0","SINGLETON STP, AS","FM-12","99999","V020","050,1,N,0010,1","22000,1,9,N","025000,1,9,9","+0260,1","+0210,1","99999,9","24,0000,9,1",,"0,1,02,1","0,1,02,1","01,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9","01,1","SYN05294733 11/75 10502 10260 20210 60004 70100 333 70000="
"94733099999","2019-01-04T04:00:00","4","-32.5833333","151.1666666","45.0","SINGLETON STP, AS","FM-12","99999","V020","090,1,N,0021,1","22000,1,9,N","025000,1,9,9","+0378,1","+0172,1","99999,9","06,0000,9,1",,"0,1,02,1","0,1,02,1","03,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9","03,1","SYN04294733 11/75 30904 10378 20172 60001 70300="
"94733099999","2019-01-04T22:00:00","4","-32.5833333","151.1666666","45.0","SINGLETON STP, AS","FM-12","99999","V020","290,1,N,0057,1","99999,9,9,N","020000,1,9,9","+0339,1","+0201,1","99999,9","24,0000,9,1",,"0,1,02,1","0,1,02,1",,"02,1","SYN05294733 11970 02911 10339 20201 60004 70200 333 70000="
"94733099999","2019-01-05T22:00:00","4","-32.5833333","151.1666666","45.0","SINGLETON STP, AS","FM-12","99999","V020","200,1,N,0026,1","99999,9,9,N","000100,1,9,9","+0209,1","+0193,1","99999,9","24,0004,3,1",,"1,1,02,1","1,1,02,1","08,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9","51,1","SYN05294733 11/01 82005 10209 20193 69944 75111 333 70004="
"94733099999","2019-01-08T04:00:00","4","-32.5833333","151.1666666","45.0","SINGLETON STP, AS","FM-12","99999","V020","070,1,N,0026,1","22000,1,9,N","025000,1,9,9","+0344,1","+0213,1","99999,9","06,0000,9,1",,"2,1,02,1","2,1,02,1","04,99,1,99,9,99,9,99999,9,99,9,99,9","02,1","SYN04294733 11/75 40705 10344 20213 60001 70222="
"""  # noqa: E501
```

Answer (score 3):

These are all great answers, but I couldn't find an editor plugin that would help me with editing "implicitly concatenated" strings, so I wrote a package to make it easier on me.

On pip (install paragraphs) if whoever's wandering this old thread would like to check it out. Formats multi-line strings the way html does (compress whitespace, two newlines for a new paragraph, no worries about spaces between lines).

```
from paragraphs import par


class SuddenDeathError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, cause: str) -> None:
        self.cause = cause

    def __str__(self):
        return par(
            f""" Y - e - e - e - es, Lord love you! Why should she die of
            {self.cause}? She come through diphtheria right enough the year
            before. I saw her with my own eyes. Fairly blue with it, she
            was. They all thought she was dead; but my father he kept ladling
            gin down her throat till she came to so sudden that she bit the bowl
            off the spoon. 

            What call would a woman with that strength in her have to die of
            {self.cause}? What become of her new straw hat that should have
            come to me? Somebody pinched it; and what I say is, them as pinched
            it done her in."""
        )


raise SuddenDeathError("influenza")
```

becomes ...

```html
__main__.SuddenDeathError: Y - e - e - e - es, Lord love you! Why should she die of influenza? She come through diphtheria right enough the year before. I saw her with my own eyes. Fairly blue with it, she was. They all thought she was dead; but my father he kept ladling gin down her throat till she came to so sudden that she bit the bowl off the spoon.

What call would a woman with that strength in her have to die of influenza? What become of her new straw hat that should have come to me? Somebody pinched it; and what I say is, them as pinched it done her in.
```

Everything lines up easily with (Vim) 'gq'

Answer (score 1):

Backslash:

```
s = "this is my really, really, really, really, really, really" +  \
    "really long string that I'd like to shorten."
```

or wrap in parens:

```
s = ("this is my really, really, really, really, really, really" + 
    "really long string that I'd like to shorten.")
```

Comment: Note that the plus is necessary. Python concatenates string literals that follow each other.

Comment: If you use parens, the plus is not necessary. If you use a plus, the parens are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Available options:

- **backslash**: `"foo" \ "bar"`
- **plus sign** followed by **backslash**: `"foo" + \ "bar"`
- **brackets**:

  - `("foo" "bar")`
  - **brackets** with **plus sign**: `("foo" + "bar")`
  - *PEP8, E502:    the backslash is redundant between brackets*

## Avoid

Avoid brackets with comma: `("foo", "bar")` which defines a tuple.

---

```
>>> s = "a" \
... "b"
>>> s
'ab'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
```

```
>>> s = "a" + \
... "b"
>>> s
'ab'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
```

```
>>> s = ("a"
... "b")
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(s)
ab
```

```
>>> s = ("a",
... "b")
>>> type(s)
<class 'tuple'>
```

```
>>> s = ("a" + 
... "b")
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(s)
ab
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `\` you can expand statements to multiple lines:

```
s = "this is my really, really, really, really, really, really" + \
"really long string that I'd like to shorten."
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a couple of methods not mentioned here for specifying large strings, but these are for very specific scenarios. YMMV...

- Multi-line blobs of text, often with formatted tokens (not quite what you were asking, but still useful):

  ```
  error_message = '''
  I generally like to see how my helpful, sometimes multi-line error
  messages will look against the left border.
  '''.strip()
  ```
- Grow the variable piece-by-piece through whatever string interpolation method you prefer:

  ```
  var = 'This is the start of a very,'
  var = f'{var} very long string which could'
  var = f'{var} contain a ridiculous number'
  var = f'{var} of words.'
  ```
- Read it from a file. PEP-8 doesn't limit the length of strings in a file; just the lines of your code. :)
- Use brute-force or your editor to split the string into managaeble lines using newlines, and then remove all newlines. (Similar to the first technique I listed):

  ```
  foo = '''
  agreatbigstringthatyoudonotwanttohaveanyne
  wlinesinbutforsomereasonyouneedtospecifyit
  verbatimintheactualcodejustlikethis
  '''.replace('\n', '')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Using **black** [https://github.com/psf/black] I format it like this.

```
   help=f"""filters, lista de filtros para cargar las base de conocimiento.
   Pueden mandarse solo algunos filtros ya que no son obligatorios,
   por ejemplo, si no se manda sts, se cargarán todos las bases de todos los estados.""",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message = f"Variable : child({type(child)}) -> is not of"\
        " type Node."
```

This syntax worked for me. Note the indentation of the second statement, it should be indented correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I've used textwrap.dedent in the past. It's a little cumbersome so I prefer line continuations now but if you really want the block indent, I think this is great.

Example Code (where the trim is to get rid of the first '\n' with a slice):

```
import textwrap as tw
x = """\
       This is a yet another test.
       This is only a test"""
print(tw.dedent(x))
```

Explanation:

dedent calculates the indentation based on the white space in the first line of text before a new line. If you wanted to tweak it, you could easily reimplement it using the `re` module.

This method has limitations in that very long lines may still be longer than you want in which case other methods that concatenate strings is more suitable.

Comment: Rather than trimming with `x[1:]` you can put a backslash after `x = """` to avoid the first newline.