# PEP8 - 80 Characters - Big Integers

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

This is somehow related to [question about big strings and PEP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874592/pep8-80-characters-big-strings).

How can I make my script that has the following line PEP8 compliant ("Maximum Line Length" rule)?

```
pub_key = {
   'e': 3226833362680126101036263622033066816222202666130162062116461326212012222403311326222666622610430466620224662364142L,
   'n': 226421003861041248462826226103022608220328242204422684232640331238220232226321616266146243302342688266846281802662666622213868114632268211186223606846623310006662260110460620201618186828411322260686632603226636226662262862212140221422102106336342228236361106240226122644614266186283436228208626640846820224661642086022346422443282224682686612228404266842316822624342226666622264826123822122031361242246432886612624262663222232331438863220022020826266366016100422L
}
```

Comment: @Anon: How? (I am being equally cryptic!)

Comment: Not too familiar with Python syntax, but assuming it's possible to perform arithmetic in this declaration, it would be something like `32268333626801261010362 * pow(10, howevermany)`, and then add more on each successive line.

Comment: Hexadecimal will shave off a few chars... but seriously, PEP8 is a style _guide_ not a style _rule_.

Comment: PEP8 is not a law.  It's a suggestion.    Why are you asking?

Comment: No-one's going to need to read those numbers; let them overflow and scroll. (80 characters is too restrictive at the best of times; sticking to it here has no benefit.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> But most importantly: know when to be
>   inconsistent -- sometimes the style
>   guide just doesn't apply.  When in
>   doubt, use your best judgment.

[source](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

In this case, I would just leave the big integers as is.

Answer (score 5):

```
'e': 3226833362680126101036263622033066816222202666130162062116461326212012L \
     * 10**45 \
     + 222403311326222666622610430466620224662364142L
```

I in no way endorse this.

Answer (score 5):

best way I can think of is

```
pub_key = {
   'e': long('3226833362680126101036263622033066816222202666130162062116461326'
             '212012222403311326222666622610430466620224662364142'),
   'n': long('2264210038610412484628262261030226082203282422044226842326403312'
             '3822023222632161626614624330234268826684628180266266662221386811'
             '4632268211186223606846623310006662260110460620201618186828411322'
             '2606866326032266362266622628622121402214221021063363422282363611'
             '0624022612264461426618628343622820862664084682022466164208602234'
             '6422443282224682686612228404266842316822624342226666622264826123'
             '8221220313612422464328866126242626632222323314388632200220208262'
             '66366016100422'),
}
```

exactly 80 chars.

Comment: Calling and additional function just to follow a style guide is overkill IMHO. Interesting solution though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. The guidelines in PEP8 are guidelines, there are situations where it's just not possible to follow the guideline.

Answer (score 2):

import this

> ...
>   Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity.
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.  Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses.  Here is where it is explained:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/