# Python: fileinput library and concatenation/line breaks

Tags: python, file-io, line-breaks

I a new to Python so bear with me.

I'be been struggling with the following and I hope you can help.

I am trying to read words from a text file (one word per line), add some text and write to an output file 'result'.

so if my input is:

```
cat
dog
horse
```

my code looks like this (of course the real code is more serious)

```
import sys, fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1]):

     f = open('results','a+')
     f.write('the following: "')
     f.write(line)
     f.write('" is an animal')
     f.write('\n')
     f.write('you could find on a farm')
     f.write('\r\n')
     f.close()
```

if there is only one word in the input file the output is fine.  Otherwise if there are three, for the first two it looks like below but the last one is fine:

```
The following:"
cat" is an animal
you could find on a farm
```

so in this example cat and dog would look like above but horse would be fine.

The command I use is `python myfile.py myinput.txt`

Why the unexpected line break and how do I fix it?

Thanks much!

Comment: I suppose, you are referring to line break after "is an animal". If so, remove the line `f.write('\n')`.

Comment: Are you sure the newline appears before `cat` and not after it?

Answer (score 1):

The newlines in your input file are read into your data - you can strip them by saying:

```
for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1]):
    line = line.strip()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Richie, all the best

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your `f.write(line)` line to read `f.write(line.strip())` then it will take care of getting rid of the extra whitespace for you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Radicand, worked great.  All the best

Answer (score 0):

`string.strip()` will strip whitespaces.

Strings are immutable - so make sure you reassign to the variable in your real code.

Also:

You are doing it in very unpythonic way. The correct way of doing this would be multiline string with string interpolation.

- [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: Thanks for your solution and the links Shabda, I will check them out so I can me more python-like :-)