# PLY yacc specifying multiline production

Tags: python, yacc, ply

Is there a way to define a multi-line production with the following syntax ? PLY expects : before ID implying one production per line.

```
def p_envvar(p):
   ''' 
   envvar : EV                    \
            ID                    \
            COLON                 \ 
            INT_VAL               \ 
            BOX_OPEN              \ 
            INT_VAL               \ 
            SEP                   \ 
            INT_VAL               \ 
            BOX_CLOSE             \ 
            STRING_VAL            \ 
            INT_VAL               \ 
            INT_VAL               \ 
            DUMMY_NODE_VECTOR     \ 
            comma_identifier_list \ 
            SEMICOLON              
   '''
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the "pipe" to separate alternate rules:

```
def p_envvar(p):
    ''' 
    envvar : EV
           | ID
           | COLON
           | INT_VAL
           | BOX_OPEN
           | INT_VAL
           | SEP
           | INT_VAL
           | BOX_CLOSE
           | STRING_VAL
           | INT_VAL
           | DUMMY_NODE_VECTOR
           | comma_identifier_list
           | SEMICOLON  
    '''
```

But using so many alternates hints to me that you probably need to simplify, (you can declare different functions which simplify to the same state:

```
def p_envar_ev():
    """envvar : EV"""

def p_envvar_id():
    """envvar : ID"""
```

... etc.  Which is easier to read than using a big if block to handle each possible case.

Comment: "envvar" is one single production spreading on multiple lines. So i cannot use alternatives. I am looking for the feature Yacc supports by allowing comments to be inserted on each line in between a production. For e.g. envvar:
      T_EV                    /* EV_               */
      T_ID                    /*  2: environment variable name */
      T_COLON                 /* :                 */
      T_INT_VAL               /*  4: type: 0 int, 1 float, 0 string, 0 data */

Comment: okay, then the answer from @ioannis-filippidis is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to spread a long `docstring` over multiple lines in a way that `PLY` understands it:

```py
def p_expr(p):
    ("""process_type : this is a very long """
     """ production rule """
     """ that does not fit on a single line """)
```

Credit for this magic goes to the OP of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string).
Notice the parentheses: they are much better than escaping with `\`, because they are compliant with [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), so syntax checkers don't complain.