# Error while using """

Tags: python

I made a function where it prints words slowly. Its very nice, but I like to mess around with it every now and then but now I am trying to use `"""` with it but it will not work. I used it a while back and it worked fine but I can't seem to make it work without getting a syntax error.

here is my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)

delay_print """

Test

"""
```

Comment: Use `'"""'` or `"\"\"\""`

Comment: Still got a syntax error.

Comment: Well, you should indicate what the syntax error is if you're expecting anyone to help you with it!!!

Comment: It seems like nobody here knows [what `"""` means in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/501250).

Comment: @cdhowie original post has been edited since posted. It seemed as if OP wanted delayed_print('"') because we couldn't see the rest: Test"""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses around the function's argument(s).

```
delay_print("""
Test
""")
```