# How does this string concatenation work?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I have some text and I want concatenate them, but they're too long. So I can do this:

```
b = 'Hello\n'\
    'Hi\n'\
    'This is a test'

print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
Hi
This is a test
```

But today I find a new way to do this, and this way is more clearer. Like this:

```
a = ('Hello\n'
     'Hi\n'
     'This is a test')

print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
Hi
This is a test
```

So now my question is: How does it work? Why does it wouldn't create a tuple or raise a `SyntaxError`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string there are numerous ways to create a multipline string, this is one of them

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks :).

Comment: Because `'a' 'b'` is a valid expression, and is equivalent to `'ab'`

Comment: @HuazuoGao And if strings in brackets can wrap without backslash? :)

Comment: @KevinGuan line breaks inside a bracket are ignored.

Comment: @HuazuoGao I understand now, thanks :)