# How do I write a long string of words to a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to write a long string of words to a text file in python3 so that the string can be written over several lines? This is what I have tried so far.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

    my_list = word_tokenize(my_text) 
    my_list_string = ' '.join(my_list)

    outfile = open("my_comp.txt", "a") 
    outfile.write(my_list_string ) 
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: Your title doesn't really match your description

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string

Comment: What do you mean by "string can be written over several lines"?

Comment: @karina Thanks, but I am not sure it works. I am getting some data from the web which I tokenize into words and which I would like to save in a text file by writing to it.  So I need to split the string up so the text file is readable.

Comment: I think you need to show example input, output, and the code you have tried

Comment: You can split the string on every `.` character and store the result to a list. And then write those elements of your list in your file.  Right?

Comment: @EbraHim, I am not sure how I would do that, since my string is of variable length

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for that in Python named `textwrap`:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> strs = "Is there a way to write a long string of words to a text file in python3 so that the string can be written over several lines? This is what I have tried so far. Is there a way to write a long string of words to a text file in python3 so that the string can be written over several lines? This is what I have tried so far. "
```

Works as below:

```
>>> print (textwrap.fill(strs, 20))
Is there a way to
write a long string
of words to a text
file in python3 so
that the string can
be written over
several lines? This
is what I have tried
so far. Is there a
way to write a long
string of words to a
text file in python3
so that the string
can be written over
several lines? This
is what I have tried
so far.
```

Or change the line length:

```
>>> print (textwrap.fill(strs, 40))
Is there a way to write a long string of
words to a text file in python3 so that
the string can be written over several
lines? This is what I have tried so far.
Is there a way to write a long string of
words to a text file in python3 so that
the string can be written over several
lines? This is what I have tried so far.
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you!  this works perfectly!  Is there a similar command for a string of numbers?  It does not seem to work even after converting the numbers to string.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code I'm not sure there is any other way then to insert a new line every nth token

But who knows how big n should be...

You should probably just leave it up to the program that is opening the file?

Comment: the program just opens the file and writes it into one  'really long' line.  Even when the string has about a 1000 words in it.

Comment: Yes. I understand. And that is how your editor deals with it. If you open it in an editor that supports line wrapping

Comment: Otherwise I would maybe loop through the tokens and append a new line to every... I don't know... 20th token?

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely worth a try!