# Saving long string in text file

Tags: python, string, save

I have a long string that I want to save in a text file with the code:

`taxtfile.write(a)`

but because the string is too long, the saved file prints as:

```
"something something ..... something something"
```

how do I make sure it will save the entire string without truncating it ?

Comment: Did you try wrapping it with """  """ to use it as multi line?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string

Comment: why do you think it will be truncated?  Show the rest of your code

Comment: it seems as if this is just a representation in your IDE/terminal.  have you confirmed the contents of the file after writing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it should work regardless of the string length

this is the code I made to show it:

```
import random

a = ''
number_of_characters = 1000000
for i in range(number_of_characters):
    a += chr(random.randint(97, 122))
print(len(a))       # a is now 1000000 characters long string

with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as textfile:
    textfile.write(a)
```

you can put number_of_characters to whatever number you like but than you must wait for string to be randomized

and this is screenshot of textfile.txt: http://prntscr.com/bkyvs9

probably your problem is in string a.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is just a representation in your IDE or terminal environment.  Try something like the following, then open the file and see for yourself if its writing in its entirety:

```
x = 'abcd'*10000
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as fh:
    fh.write(x)
```

Note the the above will write a file to whatever your current working directory is.  You may first want to navigate to your ~/Desktop before calling Python.

Also, how are you building the string `a`?  How is `textfile` being written?  If the call to `textfile.write(a)` is occurring within a loop, there may be a bug in the loop.  (Showing more of your code would help)