# Add ' ' to SQL query parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

How can I convert the account value into a string that my SQL query accepts.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

account = Range('G2').options(numbers=int).value #account number #value is 3001001000

sql = 'SELECT top 30 oraclenum,pcat,ConLenses, sum(dollars) as dollars FROM ' \
          'ConData WHERE oraclenum = {} group by oraclenum,pcat, ConLenses'.format(account)
```

How can I include the value between ' '. Kinda like **WHERE oraclenum = '3001001000'** in my SQL query. It throws an error if its not formatted as a string.

Comment: Consider [parameterized queries](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#specifying-bound-parameter-behaviors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put escaped quotes around your format expression (`\'{}\')`, though the best way is to swap quotes for double quotes and put simple quotes around your format string

```
sql = "SELECT top 30 oraclenum,pcat,ConLenses, sum(dollars) as dollars FROM " \
          "ConData WHERE oraclenum = '{}' group by oraclenum,pcat, ConLenses".format(account)
```

Comment: You could also use `"""` (triple quotes) for multi-line strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string

Comment: you're right, but in that case, it's just 2 strings on a single line, concatenated and using backslash to avoid creating a too long line.