# Word-wrapping the printing of Strings in Python

Tags: python, string, lines

I have a long string:

```
S='Hello\n i have a very very very very..... very very very very.... long Text!'
```

Printing this text creates one long line and I would like to break the line into pieces with maximum lengths of 10 or 20 characters.  I would like to break the line with `\n` and have the `\n` included in the new string.

What I'm hoping for:

```
Hello
i have a very 
very very very
..... very very 
very very.... 
long Text!
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it more clear ?

Comment: See [**`textwrap`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)

Answer (score 5):

[**`textwrap.wrap`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) allows you to wrap strings to a certain `width`.

By default it replaces whitespace with single spaces, including newlines, before wrapping.

Set `replace_whitespace=False` if you want to keep newlines, etc.

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = 'Hello\n i have a very very very very..... very very very very.... long Text!'
>>> print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(s, width=20, replace_whitespace=False)))
Hello
 i have a very
very very very.....
very very very
very.... long Text!
```

The documentation for [**`replace_whitespace`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.replace_whitespace):

> *(default: `True`)* If true, after tab expansion but before wrapping, the wrap() method will replace each whitespace character with a single space. The whitespace characters replaced are as follows: tab, newline, vertical tab, formfeed, and carriage return `('\t\n\v\f\r')`.
>
> *Note* If `expand_tabs` is false and replace_whitespace is true, each tab character will be replaced by a single space, which is not the same as tab expansion.
>
> *Note* If `replace_whitespace` is false, newlines may appear in the middle of a line and cause strange output. For this reason, text should be split into paragraphs (using str.splitlines() or similar) which are wrapped separately.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `'''YOUR BIG STRING IN PARAGRAPH WHAT YOU WANT'''`

Answer (score -4):

You can also use double quotes instead of single if that is what you want.

```
s = """ this is a very
        long string if I had the
        energy to type more and more ..."""
```

Comment: did i say anything else ? My answer was similar , why same answer again ?