# How to make a block of words a string in python

Tags: python

I was trying to write code and I needed the following string as one integer.

```
number = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
```

I wanted to know how to make it one string.

Comment: I think your question is unclear, can you provide what you expect?

Comment: What do you mean by "The whole thing apart of the string" ? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Try having the variable defined using the method described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
number = (
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
    "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
    "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
    "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
    "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
    "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
    "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
    "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
    "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
    "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
    "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
    "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
    "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
    "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
    "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
    "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
    "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
    "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
)
```

An approach with:

```
number = """
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
"""
```

Will give you newlines at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

> **bash**: line 1: Untitled1: command not found

you wrote directly in your bash command line, not in python command line. Or you executed your script file with bash, and not with python.

Moreover, I am not sure if you wrote your big string on one or several lines. If it is actually several lines, you need triple quotes `"""` not simple quotes `"`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure we are on the same page:

```
# this is a string
number = "string"

# this is an integer
number = 4 

# this is a multiline string
number = """123
456"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash before each line break:

```
number = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
```