# Multi Line Triple Quotes raw string regex not working

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex for email in python like this, whole regex in single line and it works perfectly

```python
emailRegEx = re.compile(
    r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"""
)
```

But when I try to split it into multiple lines it won't match anything, eg:

```python
emailRegEx = re.compile(
    r"""
    (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
    """
)
```

As shown above even if I put one newline in the string it won't match any emails and I get an empty list. I have tried many things changing indentation and stuff but as soon as there is a newline anywhere between the triple quotes the regex stops working.
I am using VS Code.

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone for the comments and answer, its working now, here is my working code:

```
emailRegEx = re.compile(
    r"""
    (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
    """
    , re.X)
```

Comment: The second regex starts and ends with a line break... And it's also indented, which means it contains a bunch of spaces...

Comment: Add [`re.X`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X) as the second argument and escape `#` (and literal whitespaces if you have any or are going to add any).

Comment: FYI, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/6345404 if you want multi line string, the third code snippet in the answer might be useful for you.

Comment: The regex doesn't look particularly good. Where did you get it from and what is it supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X is what you are looking for I think:

> This flag allows you to write regular expressions that look nicer and
>   are more readable by allowing you to visually separate logical
>   sections of the pattern and add comments. Whitespace within the
>   pattern is ignored [...]