# run awk date conversion in python 3.6 subprocess

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

I am trying to write the following awk line into python

```
awk -F, '{cmd="date -d \""$2"\" +%s"; cmd | getline date; printf ("%s,%d,%d\n",$1,date,$3)}' counts.csv > counts_epoch.csv
```

v1

```
import subprocess

with open("counts_epoch.csv", 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.Popen(["awk", "'{cmd="date -d \""$2"\" +%s"; cmd | getline date; printf ("%s,%d,%d\n",$1,date,$3)}'", 'counts.csv'], stdout=f)
```

This will return:

```
    subprocess.Popen(["awk", "'{cmd="date -d \""$2"\" +%s"; cmd | getline date; printf ("%s,%d,%d\n",$1,date,$3)}'", 'counts.csv'], stdout=f)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

v2:

```
with open("counts_epoch.csv", 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.call(["awk", '{cmd="date -d \""$2"\" +%s"; cmd | getline date; printf ("%s,%d,%d\n",$1,date,$3)}', 'counts.csv'], stdout=f)
```

returns:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {cmd="date -d ""$2"" +%s"; cmd | getline date; printf ("%s,%d,%d
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                            ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: {cmd="date -d ""$2"" +%s"; cmd | getline date; printf ("%s,%d,%d
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                            ^ syntax error
```

Any suggestion?  Thanks!

Comment: try putting triple quotes `"""` on the exterior

Comment: Why don't you want to use python native date/time manipulation functions/libraries?

Comment: no need for all this complex stuff. If you are to tag this "python", use python.

Comment: Hey folks, please stop delegitimizing the question! Even though I myself would also consider using pure Python in a situation like this, it doesn't make this question any less valid. There are many legitimate reasons as to why someone would want to do this.

Comment: From python you're calling awk to call shell to call date? Seems like there's got to be a simpler way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My trick for these situations is to copy the exact command using triple quotes to quote all the quotes inside of it, prefix with `r` to get a raw string and then use `shlex.split` to do split the arguments as the shell would do:

```
import shlex
cmdline = r"""awk -F, '{cmd="date -d \""$2"\" +%s"; cmd | getline date; printf ("%s,%d,%d\n",$1,date,$3)}' counts.csv"""
cmd = shlex.split(cmdline)
```

Then you can do your thing:

```
with open("counts_epoch.csv", 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=f)
```

WARNING: Tbh I haven't tested the code I just pasted here, but it should work. =)

Comment: The correct code to call date from awk would be `cmd="date -d \047$2\047 +\047%s\047"; date=((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : -1); close(cmd); printf "%s,%d,%d\n",$1,date,$3`. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline and google shell quoting rules. idk about wrapping that in python.

Comment: Thank you! It does work! A quick question: the number of quotes should be the same as something?  Or 3 is just the magic number here? @elias

Comment: @Chubaka yes, triple quotes is the Python syntax for multiline strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string/10660443#10660443