# Indentation when using multi-line strings

Tags: python, string, nested, code-readability, multilinestring

I sometimes need to use multi-line strings, but in a nested block. This works, but the readability is really poor:

```
CONDITION1 = CONDITION2 = CONDITION3 = True

if CONDITION1:
    if CONDITION2:
        s = """jkljkj
dfkjslfds
sqjdlqkj"""
    elif CONDITION3:
        s = """azeazea
azeoiuaez
azeytzae
azetzae"""
```

Using:

```
if CONDITION1:
    if CONDITION2:
        s = """jkljkj
               dfkjslfds
               sqjdlqkj"""
```

(as suggested in [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443)) is not an option because the string `s` would be:

```
jkljkj
               dfkjslfds
               sqjdlqkj
```

with unwanted left spaces.

**Question: how to use multi-line strings in nested blocks with a good readability?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap the string in [a call to `inspect.cleandoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc) and it will clean it up the same way docstrings get cleaned up (removing leading and trailing whitespace, and any level of common indentation).

```
>>> import inspect
>>> s = """jkljkj
...        dfkjslfds
...        sqjdlqkj"""
...
>>> print(s)
jkljkj
       dfkjslfds
       sqjdlqkj
>>> s = inspect.cleandoc(s)
>>> print(s)
jkljkj
dfkjslfds
sqjdlqkj
```

[`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) is also an option, but it's uglier, as it requires you to put no text on the first line, and explicitly use a line continuation character to ensure *every* line (not just the second and onwards) has identical leading indentation:

```
>>> print(textwrap.dedent('''\
...                       The^backslash is a pain
...                       so I don't recommend this approach
...                       '''))
The^backslash is a pain
so I don't recommend this approach
```

Note that while code blocks on SO don't show it properly, `dedent` left the empty final line (from putting the closing `'''` on a line by itself), where `cleandoc` would have removed it.

Comment: Thank you very much! For completeness, could you add the same example with `dedent`? (I can also edit myself if you're ok)

Comment: @Basj: Done. I think it's usually the inferior solution, so I didn't want to emphasize it, but it's occasionally useful.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer. I think `dedent` might be useful when we actually want to keep a particular indentation but just remove the left spaces. Example: `print(textwrap.dedent(""" some indented python code here """))`.

Comment: @Basj: If it's just a single line, you'd just use `.lstrip()` for that (comments don't show newlines, so it's possible you intended to put newlines and I just can't see them).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using '\'. For example:

```
if CONDITION1:

   if CONDITION2:

       s = "jkljkj "\
           "dfkjslfds "\
           "sqjdlqkj"
```

Comment: Thank you, but not an option either, because my multiline string is very long. I don't want to have to manually add `" ... "\` around each line.