# Python Multi Line SQL Statement, insert variable with single quotes

Tags: sql, python-3.x

Question is similar to [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)

However, I need to insert a variable wrapped in single quotes into my query. Cant seem to get it to work. Whenver I output my query I am just getting `2019-03-13` and I think it should be `'2019-03-13'`

```
businessDate = '2019-03-13'


    sql = f"""   
#query goes in here.
 and businessdate = {businessDate}

    """
```

error msg:

`': ('42883', '[42883] ERROR 4286:  Operator does not exist: date = int\nHINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts\n (4286) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it a raw string:

```
businessDate = r"'2019-03-13'"
```

Comment: Thanks anton, what if I wanted to use `businessDate` in my function as an argument.  Ie.   `def stack(businessDate):`

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, as long as you use the r" 'blah' " syntax:

Just play around in the shell:
`>>> biz_date=r"'1000'"`
`>>> print(biz_date)`
`'1000'`
`>>> def blah(blah):`
`...     print(blah)`
`...`
`>>> blah(biz_date)`
`'1000'`

Note that print casts to str.... so, depending on your functionality, you may have to explicitly cast it like str(blah)

Comment: Sorry Anton im having trouble following, can I message you?

Answer (score 3):

Pythonic way of achieving String interpolation is

```
businessDate = '2019-03-13'
sql = """   
 #query goes in here.
 and businessdate = '%s'
""" %businessDate

print(sql) #to check the end result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM insider_trading
    WHERE (column1|| column1) ILIKE %s
    ORDER BY accepted_datetime
"""
cursor.execute(query, ('%' + search_query + '%',))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```