# How to put a multi-row statement string into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to a store a long string (specifically a SQL query) into a variable, which I'd like to have written on more row for a better readability.

I'm using Jupyter notebook on Python 3.5 (Anaconda) if that's important.

I've tried:

```
# SQL query

query = "
SELECT
 Sued 
,ApplicationNumber_Primary
--,ApprovedLoanAmount, ApprovedLoanDuration, ApprovedMonthlyPayment, 
,RequiredLoanDuration, RequiredMonthlyPaymentAmount, RequiredPaidAmount, RequiredCoefficientK1
,ClientFreeSources, ClientTotalIncome, ClientNetIncome, ClientTotalExpenditures 
,ClientAgeToApplicationDate, ClientFamilyStatusID, ClientEmploymentDuration, CreditExposure
,CalendarQuarter, MonthOfYear, WeekOfYear, DayOfMonth, DayOfWeek, RegionID, DistrictID, ZIPcodeID 

FROM 
dbo.vRisk
GO
"
```

...which does not store the string into the variable, as I'd like.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `'''` (triple-quotes) instead of double-quotes

Comment: Of course! I thought I would just comment the statement out, but that obviously does not apply when putting it within a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multi-line strings or intersperse '\n' in it:

```
this_is_a_multiline_string = """

tata

"""
```

---

```
this_as_well = '''

tata

'''
```

---

```
and_this = "\ntata\n"
```

---

[Python.org string documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

---

```
and_like_so = ("Some string"      # no space after
               "that spans lots"  # no space after
               "of lines" )       # results in 'Some stringthat spans lotsof lines'
```

(Source for the last one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/7505395 )

Answer (score 2):

Try using triple quotes:

```
query = """
SELECT
 Sued 
,ApplicationNumber_Primary
--,ApprovedLoanAmount, ApprovedLoanDuration, ApprovedMonthlyPayment, 
,RequiredLoanDuration, RequiredMonthlyPaymentAmount, RequiredPaidAmount, RequiredCoefficientK1
,ClientFreeSources, ClientTotalIncome, ClientNetIncome, ClientTotalExpenditures 
,ClientAgeToApplicationDate, ClientFamilyStatusID, ClientEmploymentDuration, CreditExposure
,CalendarQuarter, MonthOfYear, WeekOfYear, DayOfMonth, DayOfWeek, RegionID, DistrictID, ZIPcodeID 

FROM 
dbo.vRisk
GO
"""
```