# Tidy up list comprehensions pythonically

Tags: python

FP like Haskell can bind a (var) name trivially e.g:

```
[(g y, h y) | x <- mylist, let y = f x]
```

Python does it possibly below:

```
mylist = [f(x) for x in mylist]
mylist = [(g(y), h(y)) for y in mylist]
```

Walrus assignment in Python 3.8 seems a hack to [simplify list comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#id23) :

```
[(y := f(x), g(y), h(y)) for x in mylist]
```

What is so far considered pythonic way in this case?

Comment: well, if they added it in python 3.8, that must be pythonic.

Comment: It's controversial to say the least. The walrus operator is not well-liked and is tougher to understand

Comment: It is clearly well liked enough to have ended up in the language after governance - it seems to me that that is now the way to go.

Comment: without this operator, you have to call `f(x)` 3 times. Not sure if it's pythonic or not, but the performance suffers.

Comment: @modesitt sure, after Guido stopped being the BDFL over it. Making it into the language hand-waves the collateral damage

Comment: This is all opinion-based. The code works; it should be closed

Comment: you can chain 2 comprehensions to get your result in one line. With := operator, you _have_ to create a triplet, not a couple like before.

Comment: I wouldn't say the walrus version "works"; it creates a list of 3-tuples, rather than a list of 2-tuples like the original definition of `mylist`.

Comment: Mean you could of course do `[(g((y := f(x))), h(y)) for x in mylist]` but that might be contentious

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre, the walrus option here has changed the intent as side effect: tuple of two elements to three

Comment: @roganjosh I disagree wholeheartedly; Stack Overflow is not just a place for questions about code that doesn't work. See for example this question, which presents working Python code and asks for a more "Pythonic" solution, with over 1000 upvotes, and **zero** downvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string

Comment: @kaya3 yeah, a question asked over 7 years ago. The walrus operator is controversial; all this question does is flare up people's opinion. It's not broken code and there aren't any performance gains obvious. It literally just stands to bring up opinion. That's a specific close reason.

Comment: Why not simply use `[(g(f(x)), h(f(x))) for x in mylist]` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct use of the walrus operator to create 2-tuples would be

```
mylist = [(g(y:=f(x)), h(y)) for x in mylist]
```

which, yes, is even more horrendous than the 3-tuple version. If you want to forgo the walrus operator, use the version which `:=` was supposed to obviate:

```
mylist = [(g(y), h(y)) for x in mylist for y in [f(x)]]
```

or more simply

```
mylist = [(g(y), h(y)) for y in map(f, mylist)]
```

I would not say the walrus operator is *always* so ungainly, but it seems to be more trouble than it is worth here.

Comment: The 1st oneliner is what i'm looking for!

Comment: Of the three, I would recommend the *third* most strongly.

Comment: The 1st one seems more flexible to me but introduces new vars to the outer scope even unwanted. The 3rd need still define `f` elsewhere.

Comment: PEP-572 discusses the rationale for `y` being defined in the containing scope, unlike `x` which is restricted to the comprehension. All three need to define `f` somewhere else. My main opposition to the first one is the asymmetrical expressions; I would have preferred something like `[let y = f(x) in (g(y), h(y)) for x in mylist]`, though adding new keywords to Python is much harder than new operators.

Comment: The 1st is the application of `f`, the 3rd the definition then need lambda expression if oneliner is preferred.

Comment: What lambda expression?

Comment: E.g. `[(g(y:=x+1),h(y)) for x in mylist]` vs `[(g(y), h(y)) for y in map(lambda x: x+1, mylist)]`

Comment: And, does the 3rd still suffer from double iterating over the list?

Comment: Ah, ok. I'd still prefer either 2 or 3 here to avoid the asymmetry of the tuple expression.

Comment: The third does not, as `map` doesn't do anything until you actually request an item from it. Think of `map` as applying a wrapper around `mylist`; each time you request an item, it passes through `f` first.

Comment: Any reference to `map` as the wrapper here? It's already lengthy, thx a lot!

Comment: That's just what an instance of the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) class does; `map(f, xs)` is essentially the same as `(f(x) for x in xs)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that `map` is more appropriate for applying an operation on every element of a list.

```
mylist = map(f, mylist)
mylist = list(map(lambda x: (g(x), g(x)), mylist))
```

Comment: Guido wanted to ditch `map` so I'm not sure how this is definitively "pythonic"

Comment: Guido also wanted to ditch `lambda`; he's not a fan of functional techniques in general (as witnessed by `reduce`'s demotion from built-in to the `functools` module).

Comment: But list comprehensions *are* a functional technique!

Comment: @kaya3 Ironic, isn't it? :) But even in Haskell (where Python borrowed it from), it is syntactic sugar used to *hide* the application of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python doesn't have ["let ... in ..." expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression), the cleanest way is to write a function and call it.

```py
def apply_g_h(x):
    y = f(x)
    return g(y), h(y)

mylist = [ apply_g_h(x) for x in mylist ]
```

If you really prefer it as a one-liner, then a lambda function can serve the same purpose:

```py
mylist = [ (lambda y: (g(y), h(y)))(f(x)) for x in mylist ]
```

This works because a "let" expression `let x = e1 in e2` is equivalent to `(lambda x: e2)(e1)`. I've had to do this occasionally when limited to only writing expressions (to be passed to `eval`), but it's not very readable, so I think the first solution is much better.

Comment: The 2nd option of immediate call to lambda expression is also great to me!

Answer (score 0):

Some other questions are linked here (such as [python how to declare variable in for comprehension without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862347/python-how-to-declare-variable-in-for-comprehension-without-iterating#68862550)) so let me answer a slightly more general question.

How to bind a local variable within a `for` comprehension without iteration. The trick is to create a singleton list and iterate over it such as `for b in [u(a)]` in the following.

One might find this ugly and cryptic, but it is the most concise way I have found.

```
[x for a in f(x) for b in [u(a)] if v(b) for x in w(b)]
```