# python how to declare variable in for comprehension without iterating

Tags: python-3.x, for-comprehension

Is there some sort of `let` syntax for a variable in the python `for` comprehension?  What I mean is a way to bind a newly named variable like an iteration, but without actually iterating anything.

```py
data = [w for y in f() let z = g(y) if z > 0 for w in h(z)]
```

This can be done in Python in a more cryptic way of course by making a singleton list, `[g(y)]`, which is what I do, being not a python expert.

```py
data = [w for y in f() for z in [g(y)] if z > 0 for w in h(z)]
```

The `let` syntax exists for the equivalent of `for` comprehensions in Common Lisp, Clojure, and Scala, so I wondered whether there is corresponding syntax in Python as well.

Answer (score 0):

strating from `python 3.8` you can try the assignment operator `:=` like this:

```
data = [w for y in f() if (z:=g(y)) > 0 for w in h(z)]
```

if there is no actual need for this variable, you can just write:

```
data = [w for y in f() if g(y) > 0 for w in h(g(y))]
```

for more info refer: [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Comment: yes, but but in your   suggestion   I have to call `g(y)` twice, right?  Which means there IS a need to bind the value of `g(y)` to a variable.

Comment: correct, the assignment expressions are only available from version 3.8, for previous versions I guess it's better to use **your** second option with the singleton list.