# Can I use line breaks in a python format funtion print line?

Tags: python, printing, formatting, line-breaks

This is the line of code I want to break up, it works fine but it is a very long line, how does one use line breaks in a format function print line like this?

```
return '{0.name} is a {0.sex} rabbit and has {0.fur_colour} fur and {0.eye_colour} eyes, {0.name} is of the {0.breed} breed of rabbits.\n{0.name} is '.format(paul)+ disp_age
```

Comment: That's just a string, not a print line function. You can break up at the sum, by doing `\ ` at the end of the line

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your whole splitted string into `()`

```
return ("{0.name} is a {0.sex} rabbit"
    " and has {0.fur_colour} fur and "
    "{0.eye_colour} eyes, {0.name} is "
    "of the {0.breed} breed of rabbits.\n"
    "{0.name} is ").format(paul)+ disp_age
```

This answer about multi-line strings was useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/7042357

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I was looking for thanks.