# Why doesn't multi line print in python work for single and double quoted strings?

Tags: python-3.x, string

This program doesn't work

```
print("test
test")
```

This runs as expected

```
print("""test
test""")
```

Is this simply because Python interpreter allows multi line strings for triple quotes, or there is some difference in the way it interprets the triple quotes?

Comment: Python allows newlines in triple-quoted strings. That's what they are for, and why they're sometimes called multi-line string literals.

Answer (score 0):

When You manually type `\n` it is interpreted as command to execute, you should use triple quotes to enter newlines(`\n`) manually.
 Either `"""#Your string"""` or `'''#Your string'''`

Answer (score 0):

the triple quotes are also used to define multi line string that why ,

```
print("""test
test""")
```

the above code works,

You can also use the `\` such as,

```
print("test \
test")
```

Have a look at this question-[Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)