# How to search r""" in Google, Bing or DuckDuckGo?

Tags: python, search-engine

I am new to Python. I work with other people's code. When I don't understand something, I just do a internet search to know more about it. Yesterday I came across something like this,

```py
r"""This is a some text that has spanned multiple
lines and my editor color syntax and highlighting
has made it a different color like a string"""
```

In that code, it looked like a comment. But I was intrigued and I wanted to know more about it. So I searched for `r"""` in DuckDuckGo, Google, Bing and neither of them pointed it at the right place. I even tried Advanced Search and Google just added some extra quotes like this `"r""""`. I only got results for the R programming language.

My question is, how does one search for term like that in a search engine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string

Comment: For searching, try to describe the thing if you can't find it literally. Googling for *"r prefix" "triple quotes" python* might be a good start. Google actually now recognizes pronounceable synonyms for many punctuation marks, so you could try "r-double-quote-double-quote-double-quote" as a search term.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685615/how-can-i-use-a-search-engine-to-search-for-special-characters