# How to start a new line of code when printing strings

Tags: python, printing

Say I want to print the following sentence but it appears too long in the code editor:

```
print('This sentence is so so so very very very very long long long lonoooooong')
```

How do I start a new coding line in the code editor, something like this:

```
print('This sentence is so so so very very \
     very very long long long lonoooooong')
```

But the code above doesn't quite work because in the output, there is a big gap between the 2 sentences separated by `\`:

```
This sentence is so so so very very      very very long long long lonoooooong
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the brackets of `print` to enclose the parts of a string over multiple lines, e.g.:

```
print('This sentence is so so so very very '
     'very very long long long lonoooooong')
```

Output:

```
This sentence is so so so very very very very long long long lonoooooong
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print('This sentence is so so so very very very'
      ' very long long long lonoooooong'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for that sentence and you can edit it in the codes (rather than a variable). You might want to try:

'''
print("This sentence is so so so very very\nvery very long long long lonoooooong")
'''

It should come out as

This sentence is so so so very very
very very long long long lonoooooong

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print('''sentence is so so so very very
very very long long long lonoooooong''')
```