# Python Script - Datetime Stamp Issue using Insert Statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute a python script.

Script:

```
   dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO photos(id,name,type,updated_at_ms) values("+str(id)+","+json.dumps(url)+",1,'%s');".format(dt))
    self.mydb.commit()
```

The script runs successfully, but the timestamp doesn't get populated. The value for the timestamp is "0000-00-00 00:00:00.000" across all rows.

The variable has a value which I checked with the Print statement but somehow it won't work with an Insert statement.

Please let me know what am I missing here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)

Comment: not really. Thank you for your suggestion.