# Python f format print statement break line without showing white spaces

Tags: python-3.x

```
def test():
    var1 = "hello"
    var2 = "world"

    print(f"This is just a test so i dont know? Im gonna spam some word to it exceeds 80 characters maybe. is this more than enough already? Okay maybe. Just wanted to say, {var1}, {var2} to everyone!"
```

How do I break the print statement? If I break it using `\` like below, it'll print out white spaces too.

```
def test():
    var1 = "hello"
    var2 = "world"

    print(f"This is just a test so i dont know? Im gonna spam some word to it exceeds \
                        80 characters maybe. is this more than enough already? Okay maybe. \
                        Just wanted to say, {var1}, {var2} to everyone!"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)

Comment: @SuperStormer sadly it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eliminate the unwanted whitespaces by adjusting your indentation.  Outside a function, you do it like this:

```
var1 = "hello"
var2 = "world"
print(f"This is just a test so i dont know? Im gonna spam some word to it exceeds \
80 characters maybe. is this more than enough already? Okay maybe. \
Just wanted to say, {var1}, {var2} to everyone!")
```

Inside a function, you do it like this:

```
def test():
    var1 = "hello"
    var2 = "world"

    print(f"This is just a test so i dont know? Im gonna spam some word to it exceeds \
80 characters maybe. is this more than enough already? Okay maybe. \
Just wanted to say, {var1}, {var2} to everyone!")
```

Comment: This makes it look weird especially when the function is already very far to the right. but i guess that solves it.