# How to print in multiple line in python

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am writing a small function; the result must be displayed in multiple lines; how to do this

```
def display(self):
    return f'Name: {self.name},\n Roll no:{self.rollno}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)

Comment: Well, you seem to have already written a function that *returns* a multi-line string. So what exactly are you asking? What do you mean by *displayed*? Your function seems to be a class method (judging by the `self` parameter), so if you have an instance called `obj` and you simply call `print(obj.display())`  for example, the string will be correctly displayed in two lines (if that's what you are asking).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"""` or `'''` to start and end a multiline string in Python. Example:

```py
def try_print_this():
    return """This is
a multiline
string in Python"""

print(try_print_this())
```

In your case that should be:

```py
def display(self):
    return f'''Name: {self.name},
Roll no:{self.rollno}'''
```