# How to send POST request with each payload on its own line using Python requests

Tags: python, google-analytics, python-requests

I have to send a POST request to the `/batch` endpoint of : 'https://www.google-analytics.com'.

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch) I have to send the request to `/batch` endpoint and **specify each payload on its own line.**

I was able to achieve this using **POSTMAN** as follows:

[image: Postman]

My query is to make a POST request using Python's `requests` library

I tried something like this :

```
import requests

text = '''v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=bookmarks&ev=13
v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=upvotes&ev=65
v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=questions&ev=15
v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=postviews&ev=95'''

response = requests.post('https://www.google-analytics.com/batch', data=text)
```

but it doesn't works.

**UPDATE**

I Tried this and it works !

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.google-analytics.com")
payload = "v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-200248207-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=bookmarks&ev=13\r\nv=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-200248207-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=upvotes&ev=63\r\nv=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-200248207-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=questions&ev=11\r\nv=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-200248207-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=postviews&ev=23"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
}
conn.request("POST", "/batch", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
```

But the question remains open, what's the issue with `requests` here.

Comment: Please Post your code and not screenshots.

Comment: ```response.status_code``` gives ```200```. What do you expect your code to do ?

Comment: As mentioned here : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits#overview    It gives 200 even if it is malformed. But I can confirm from my analytics dashboard that request isn't made successfully when using python requests.

Comment: try simply remove `\\n`

Comment: I tried validating your requests to this end point as mentioned in the docs - ```https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect```. The response says that ```tid``` is invalid. May be you have to check that. @Prakhar

Comment: @Ram That's a secret data which I can't share that's why i have replaced that with XXXXXX. Wait I will create a testing account then update the question with `tid`

Comment: May be you could make a POST request to ```https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect``` with actual values and check the status. You can find the status in ```response.json()```. @Prakhar

Comment: ```/collect``` is for making a single hit, I have to send 10-12 hits at a time which according to documentation is best with ```/batch``` but unfortunately there is nothing like ```/debug/batch```. (I checked)

Comment: @Prakhar But you could make just one hit and check if everything is working fine. Right ?

Comment: @Ram i checked, /debug/collect returns ```valid=true``` but actually it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I figured out the solution myself.

Updating for others help.

The problem was I was working on `AWS Cloud9` and as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#using-a-proxy-server)

> Some environments are not able to send hits to Google Analytics directly. Examples of this are older mobile phones that can't run JavaScript or corporate intranets behind a firewall.

So we just need to include the `User Agent parameter`

> `ua=Opera/9.80`

in each of our `payloads`

It works !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to double-escape the newline symbol.

Moreover, you don't need the newline symbol at all for the multi-line string.

And also the indentations you put in your multi-line string are counted:

```
test = '''abc
def
ghi'''

print(test)
```

Here's an SO answer that explains this with some additional ways to make long stings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/4570170

Now the request body.

The documentation says

> payload_data – The BODY of the post request. The body must include exactly 1 URI encoded payload and must be no longer than 8192 bytes.

So try uri-encoding your payload:

```
text = '''v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=bookmarks&ev=13
v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=upvotes&ev=65
v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=questions&ev=15
v=1&cid=43223523&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=aggregated_stats&ea=daily_kpi&el=postviews&ev=95'''

text_final = requests.utils.quote(text)

response = requests.post('https://www.google-analytics.com/batch', data=text_final)
```

Comment: @Chillie Thanks that's was an issue, I corrected that. But it still doesn't works.

Comment: @Prakhar i've updated the answer, try uri-encoding the data.

Comment: ok i tried still it doesn't work. I tried making it work using ```http.client``` it works. But not with ```requests```

Comment: @Prakhar then inspect your request body in `http.client` and see how it's sending your payloads. Debugging and manually inspecting the requests/responses is key here.