# How do I best handle pylint long-line checks with f-strings?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, f-string, long-lines

Let me preface this with the fact that I love both `pylint` *and* f-strings. Unfortunately, company policy mandates a maximum line length and using long f-strings is disagreeing with that policy. For example:

```py
xyzzy = f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} {last_name}) is too long')
```

I know that, with `str.format()`, there's a fairly easy way to do it:

```py
xyzzy = 'Let us pretend this line (from {} {}) is too long'.format(
    first_name, last_name)
```

However, I don't really want to give up the main benefit of f-strings, the ability to have the data inline with the surrounding text, so I don't have to go looking for it.

I *could* do two separate f-string and concatenate them with `+`, but that seems a bit wasteful.

Is there a way to do a *single* f-string but broken up in such a way as to stop `pylint` complaining about the length? I'm thinking something like the following (mythical) method where it does what C does in auto-magically concatenating string literals:

```
xyzzy = f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} '
        f'{last_name}) is too long')
```

Note there's not much *structural* difference between that and one with `+` at the end of the first line, but I suspect the latter would be two distinct operations in the byte-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess in your case it is best to use the usual line continuation method using a backslash `\`:

```
xyzzy = f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} ' \
        f'{last_name}) is too long')
```

Note that it generates the same bytecode as a single line:

```
>>> def foo():
...   return "long line"
... 
>>> def bar():
...   return "long " \
...   "line"
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('long line')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('long line')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

That being said, CPython compiler is pretty smart when it comes to simple optimisations:

```
>>> def foobar():
...   return "long " + "line"
... 
>>> dis.dis(foobar)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('long line')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I thought maybe that would not work with f-strings but it does. It optimises the intermixed string constants and calculated values in the same manner as if I had the whole thing on one line.

Comment: It gives following warning message: `‘\’: E502 the backslash is redundant between brackets`

Comment: @alper There are no brackets in the example. Also _what_ gives that warning? Those are pylint warnings, nothing to do with CPython.

Comment: I was getting them in `pylint`. Ah if I create them inside `print()` , brackets of `print` will cause the warning message

Answer (score 1):

I found the following three ways to solve this issue:

```
first_name = 'John'
last_name = 'Doe'

foo = f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} ' \
    f'{last_name}) is too long ' \
    f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} ' \
    f'{last_name}) is too long'

bar = f"""Let us pretend this line (from {first_name}
{last_name}) is too long
Let us pretend this line (from {first_name}
{last_name}) is too long""".replace('\n', ' ')

xyz = (
    f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} '
    f'{last_name}) is too long '
    f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} '
    f'{last_name}) is too long'
)
```

I personally think that the last variant looks the cleanest, but if you want to use a *single* f-string, then see the second option. More ideas can be found at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string).

Answer (score 1):

You can surround the string by parenthesis and use python's implicit concatenation of string:

```py
xyzzy = (
    f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} '
    f'{last_name}) is too long).'
    ' This is a non f-string part of the string'
)
```

Black can do that semi-automatically you just have to add a `'f'` inside your string after the 87th character and apply auto-formatting (or `"f"` after the first time you apply it).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to concatenate with a backslash (`\`):

```
xyzzy = f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} ' \
    f'{last_name}) is too long')
```

Or with a not recommended way :)

```
xyzzy = ''.join((f'Let us pretend this line (from {first_name} ', 
    f'{last_name}) is too long'))
```