# Is it possible to write each sentence of a text of a different line?

Tags: python

So I was wondering if it was possible to have the program write each line of say, a story on a different line, without you having to type each of the sentences in a separate `print` function. It's silly but also a serious question.

Comment: What is each sentence of a text? How are they determined?

Comment: they would be determined by a period.

Comment: Use something like `for sentence in text.split('.'): print(sentence+'.')`

Comment: Related: [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = 'this is. the text. that you. want to separate'.replace('.','\n')
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
To print text spanning different lines just enclose the text within three single quotation marks.

```
print('''line 1
         line 2
         line 3''')

sample_text = '''This is a text.
It spans across multiple lines.
I can put this within triple quotes'''
```

OR

```
sample_text = "This is a text.\n It spans across multiple lines.\nI can use escape sequences."
```

Both of the above will give the same output.

Comment: What if the text is in a variable? Or read from a file?

Comment: What? What do you mean? I don't see how your answer answers the question. You propose to manually write the whole string. IU doubt that what the question is asking for. Assuming you have a string as `"hello. this is. a text."` every sentence (separated by a period) should be printed on a separate line...