# How to pass python variable to sparql query?

Tags: python, python-requests, sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I would expect/hope something like this works:

```
import requests

my_variable = 'wd:Q1968435'

url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
query = """
    SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
        WHERE 
            {
            ?item wdt:P31 "+my_variable+".
            SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
            }
    """
r = requests.get(url, params= {'format': 'json', 'query': query})
data = r.json()
```

But this does not work. Is there a simple solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check closely how you're concatenating the `query` string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking as example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660477/12511801), I modified your code for concatenating your multiline string as follows:

```
import requests

my_variable = 'wd:Q1968435'

url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
query = (
    'SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ',
     '   WHERE ',
     '       {',
     '       ?item wdt:P31 '+my_variable+'.', 
     '       SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }'
     '       }'
)

# make request: 
r = requests.get(url, params= {'format': 'json', 'query': "".join(query)})
data = r.json()
print("".join(query)) # Here I'm printing the string concatenated as single line.

# Print the result of the request.
print(data)
```

The result of the previous string concatenation is:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel    WHERE        {       ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q1968435.       SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
```

Comment: great! thank you for the answer and the other linked example

Comment: @MrTree you're welcome. BTW, I'm learning Python, so, as advice, I think we should search for the best way to build a mulltiline string - but, I'm glad my solution is good enough for you.

Comment: I prefere to use f strings ```query = (
    f'SELECT ?item ?itemLabel '
     '   WHERE '
     '       {'
     '       ?item wdt:P31 {my_variable}.'
     '       SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }'
     '       }'
)```

Comment: @Marco what you mean exactly? – What could be a better way to build a multiline string?

Comment: @MrTree, in the linked answer you can find other alternatives.

Comment: @Marco I see, but I think your attempt is quite readable and handy ;) There also shouldn't occur performance issues.