# How can we use a python string variable in a SPARQL query?

Tags: python, sparql, sparqlwrapper, knowledge-graph

I want to use python string variables in my SPARQL query without an IRI (for the sake of looping through a list of variables etc. I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work.

Please ignore the prefixes etc. I just changed them for the sake of posting my code here and they do not really affect the error or question.

This is what I tried:

```
variable = "apple"

knows_query = """ 
PREFIX example: <http://www.example.com>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE {
    ?s rdfs:label | example:someExample | example:anotherExample """+variable+""" .
}"""
```

This gives the error:

```
ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery}, found '?'  (at char 201), (line:6, col:9)
```

I have tried `"+variable+"` but it doesn't work either.

The above code should achieve what this code achieves:

```
knows_query = """ 
PREFIX example: <http://www.example.com>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE {
    ?s rdfs:label | example:someExample | example:anotherExample "apple" .
}"""
```

I also tried [How to pass python variable to sparql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71623202/how-to-pass-python-variable-to-sparql-query) but it doesn't seem to work for some reason, giving a similar error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your expected query string has the word `apple` within quotes, whereas your query simply includes it in without the quotes. (If in doubt, print it out.)

You must add quotes before and after the word occurs.

I'm using [Python f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), available in Python 3.6 and above, which is much better for readability and code maintenance.

```
knows_query = f""" 
PREFIX example: <http://www.example.com>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE {
    ?s rdfs:label | example:someExample | example:anotherExample "{variable}" .
}"""
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this solution earlier but it doesn't quite work because of all the 'WHERE {...}'. I fixed this by doing this 'WHERE{{...}}. But thanks for contributing to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

My reply probably arrive late but you can use this solution:

```
variable = 'apple'

query = """
PREFIX example: <http://www.example.com>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE {
    ?s rdfs:label | example:someExample | example:anotherExample '%s' .
}""" %(variable)
```