# Split string by Nth occurrence of a character

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a string with some comma-separated values:

```py
my_string = 'abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls,jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh,da'
```

I need to split this string by every 5th occurrence of a comma.

Code I tried:

```
a = re.findall("\,".join(["[^,]+"] * 5), my_string)
```

Current output:

```py
['abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls', 'jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh']
```

Expected output:

```py
['abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls', 'jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh', 'da']
```

How to get remaining string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split the definition of a long string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/how-do-i-split-the-definition-of-a-long-string-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: @sahasrara62, that's a completely different question. It's about the *definition* of a long string, so about splitting something in the source code. This question is about splitting input text according to a certain pattern, which is really different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by splitting on , and joining in chunks:

```
seq = my_string.split(',')
size = 5
[','.join(seq[pos:pos + size]) for pos in range(0, len(seq), size)]
```

Output:

```
['abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls', 'jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh', 'da']
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `regex` for this. Just try something like this:

```py
ls = 'abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls,jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh,da'.split(",")
[",".join(ls[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(ls), 5)]
```

results into this:

```
['abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls', 'jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh', 'da']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str_test = "abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls,jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh,da"

splitStr = str_test.split(",")
_5str = [",".join(splitStr[i : i + 5]) for i in range(0, len(splitStr), 5)]
print(_5str)
>>>['abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls', 'jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh', 'da']
```

Comment: I fixed it, but wasn't allowed to post

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way by counting the `,` occuerence

```
>>> my_string = 'abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls,jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh,da'
>>> start = 0
>>> end = 0
>>> count = 0
>>> 
>>> result = []
>>> for i, v in enumerate(my_string):
...     if v==',':
...             count+=1
...     if count ==5:
...             count = 0
...             result.append(my_string[start:i])
...             end = i
...             start = i+1
... 
>>> if end != len(my_string)-1:
...     result.append(my_string[star:])

>>> if end != len(my_string)-1:
...     result.append(my_string[start:])
... 
>>> result
['abc,kjj,hg,kj,ls', 'jsh,ku,lo,sasad,hh', 'da']
```