# How to insert single quote SQL queries into Trino as varchar?

Tags: sql, trino

I have SQL queries in some data that looks includes single quotes, e.g. `SELECT * from TABLE where date = '2022-11-11'` this is causing issues when inserting into a table because of single quotes.

I'm using Python to process the data coming in but replacing the ''' with '\'' doesn't seem to be working. I thought escaping the single quotes but would work but queries to INSERT still fail. What would be the best way to handle inserting single quote SQL queries into a VARCHAR column?

Comment: You should be using parametized queries instead of string concatenation values.

Comment: Haven't heard about those before. What are those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double single quotes are used to escape single quote in Presto/Trino:

```sql
select 'SELECT * from TABLE where date = ''2022-11-11''';
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| SELECT * from TABLE where date = '2022-11-11' |

So you can format your query correspondingly

Comment: This now fails on multi-line queries. Is there a way to handle long multiline queries? All I can think of is splitting it into an array of strings..

Comment: @Paul have you tried anything from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10660435/2501279)?

Comment: I ended up replacing all `\n` with `\t` and it works now.