# I am struggling to fix a sqlite3 table in my program

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

File "source_file.py", line 154
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cage_info Integer/
^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

I've gone through the entire script to see what's wrong and what can be fixed

Comment: Your string literal contains an end-of-line character. In other words, you started a string and did not end it on the same line. What is unclear to you about the error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split the definition of a long string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/how-do-i-split-the-definition-of-a-long-string-over-multiple-lines)