Unterminated f-string literal
The following code
message = (
           f'Lembrete de que existe uma reserva para amanhã de *{dayAfter}* 
           {dayAfterCellphone} para a carrinha que estás a usar.'
          )

is giving me the following error
SyntaxError: unterminated f-string literal (detected at line 44); Error ID: 49c34848

At first, when I deleted the '*' characters the error was prompted in another line so I thought it was beacause of the '*' characters. I misunderstood the cause of the error. Thank you for the answers!

It's not because of the asterisks. It's the line break.

It's not the star, it's the fact that the string literal is split over two lines - you cannot do that with literals with one quote mark at each end (the f has nothing to do with this).  You either need to use triple quotes (but note that the indentation on the second line becomes part of the string), or two separate literals, each of which is quoted at both ends (the enclosing parentheses allows this to span multiple lines)

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/how-do-i-split-the-definition-of-a-long-string-over-multiple-lines

You cannot break a single-quoted string over a line. But you can write…
message = (
           f'Lembrete de que existe uma reserva para amanhã de *{dayAfter}* '
           f'{dayAfterCellphone} para a carrinha que estás a usar.'
          )

Two string literals separated only by whitespace are merged into a single str object at compile time.
