# Linebreak a raw string

Tags: python, code-formatting, rawstring

I'm looking for a good way to linebreak long raw strings in python.
The reason for that is, that I'm often using windows path together with `pathlib`s `Path`, as this allows me for convenient copy pasting on both windows and *nix like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
my_long_path = Path(r'C:some\very\long\path')
```

Now naturally, filepaths can get quite long and for better code formatting I sometimes want to linebreak raw strings.

What doesn't work is tripple quotes, because of the linebreak symbol:

```
a = r'''some\
very\long\path'''

--> 'some\\\nvery\long\path'
```

So the only option I know is:

```
a = r'some\'\
r'very\long\path'
```

It works but feels a little un-pythonic. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use brackets:
This is also found here [How to write very long string that conforms with PEP8 and prevent E501](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874592/how-to-write-very-long-string-that-conforms-with-pep8-and-prevent-e501)

```
s = ("this is my really, really, really, really, really, really, " # comments ok
     "really long string that I'd like to shorten.")

print(s)
>>>> this is my really, really, really, really, really, really, really long string that I'd like to shorten.
```

Comment: but that's not a raw string anymore, or is it?

Comment: Yes it is a raw string