# How to write block of lines into text files in python

Tags: python

I want to write some block of text to .txt file.

example I am having text like:

```
" <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
  ParameterAllocation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns="CGenCorrXSD_V1">  "
```

how can I write this text block into .txt file using python.

If I use File_name.write("--") it will write only single line and I have to use "\n" for every new line. I want to preserve same indentation format as well.

any easy method exists?

Comment: Write your text in a multi-line string and write that one string.

Comment: If you don't want to use a multiline string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874592/how-to-write-very-long-string-that-conforms-with-pep8-and-prevent-e501

Comment: @Tzane This has nothing to do with writing to files and will not add new line characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use """ for multi lines as follows:

```
  Textdata = """ <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
      ParameterAllocation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns="CGenCorrXSD_V1">  """
    
    with open("Text.txt","w") as file:
        file.write(Textdata)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use `"""` instead of `"` such as what follows:

```py
myData = """ <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
  ParameterAllocation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns="CGenCorrXSD_V1">  
"""
# The rest of the code which saves `myData` into a file
```