# Is there a way to not wrap line when doing PyDev organize import?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

PyDev's "Organize Import" will wrap the line at 80 char width like below:
from xyz import A, B, C, \
D, E, F

Is there a way to disable that wrap? or to extend the width?
I tried increasing the line width in eclipse settings, but it didn't seem to work. I think that's only specific in Java editors and not PyDev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible... the margin may be raised in window > preferences > general > editors > text editors > print margin column.

And the option to break in multilines or not may be changed in window > preferences > pydev > editor > code style > imports > 'allow multiline imports...'

Comment: @Fabio: Thanks for the answer! I'm unchecking the "allow multiline imports" with LiClipse 3.1 (which uses PyDev 5.2.0), and when I do Ctrl-Shift-O, missing imports are still being broken up in multiple lines. Here's a screenshot of my config: http://pasteboard.co/noHeiVVga.png. Also wondering, if already present, multiline imports are supposed to be reformated as single line imports? Because this also is not happening.

Comment: I just checked it here and the issue is in the PEP8 compliant organizer (that version is really always breaking -- please create a bug report for that in https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev).

Comment: I've created the ticket here: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/749

Answer (score 2):

```
from xyz import (A, B, C,
                 D, E, F)
```

Or

```
from xyz import A, B, C
from xyz import D, E, F
```

If the line is to wide to be shown it is too wide to be read easily. See [Why should Python PEP-8 specify a maximum line length of 79 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88942/why-should-python-pep-8-specify-a-maximum-line-length-of-79-characters/88948#88948)