# Why python code shouldn't exceed 80 chars?

Tags: python

Hello Stackoverflow users,

Why it is recommended to not exceed 80 chars in python code ? I feel like it's completely useless, but someone told me it was important for some reason, what are these reasons and is it really important ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you saw thar?

Comment: A single line maybe? Historical reasons mostly, when the terminal was 80 chars wide. Still relevant as believed to be the optimal max line length to be readable with comfort. Not specific to Python.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88942/why-does-pep-8-specify-a-maximum-line-length-of-79-characters

Comment: This is mainly a style guideline, that you are *free to ignore or modify for your purposes*.