# How let python run its script in line

Tags: python, syntax

How can we use python run its script in line ? e.g.

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script("test-script.py")
for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
   print(name)
```

Have tried such its one line:

```
$ python -c 'from modulefinder import ModuleFinder; finder = ModuleFinder(); finder.run_script("/usr/bin/xbacklight"); for name, mod in finder.modules.items(): print(name)'
  File "<string>", line 1
    from modulefinder import ModuleFinder; finder = ModuleFinder(); finder.run_script("/usr/bin/xbacklight"); for name, mod in finder.modules.items(): print(name)
                                                                                                              ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to do it finely working? Thanks before

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you like to do this? The [PEP 8 guidelines](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) suggest a maximum line length of 79 characters as a standard (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88942/why-does-pep-8-specify-a-maximum-line-length-of-79-characters) and associated answers for more in-depth discussion and arguments on why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your for-each inside a **list comprehension** in order to make it work using a single-line instruction.

The command becomes

```bash
python -c 'from modulefinder import ModuleFinder; finder = ModuleFinder(); finder.run_script("/usr/bin/xbacklight"); [print(name) for name, mod in finder.modules.items()]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a here-document. Once you've entered `<<something`, the shell will pipe all input until it sees "something" again to stdin. Commonly, "EOF" is used.

```
$ python <<EOF
> from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
> finder = ModuleFinder()
> finder.run_sctript("test-script.py")
> for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
>     print(name)
> EOF
```